# World Renowned Stack Exchange Podcast episode upcoming?

Tags: discussion, podcast

I have been listening to the [Stack Exchange Podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/) recently and I am thoroughly enjoying it.  But apart from listening to some slightly old episodes I am jonesing for more.

Any idea on when the next episode will be out?  Currently the newest episode is [Episode 54](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/11/podcast-54-the-one-with-all-the-anachronisms/).

Comment: The podcasts have always been on a semi-irregular basis. There will be a new episode when there is a new episode.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ha, a slightly more rhetorical answer than I was looking for. I was wondering because it seems as though it has been a little longer than usual since the last one.  And I am aware that this may not be known.

Comment: Well, you are mostly asking the community here; and we don't know either. :-)

Comment: Careful you don't delay them dealing with issues your username causes, Bobby Tables! :-)

Comment: Hopefully, the next episode will not be content-free (as Scott Hanselman once put it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are there any more planned?

You would have to define "planned."

Are we intending to make more?

Yes, ab·so·LUTE·ly

But dates are still TBD.

Comment: Thanks, I am happy to know they are still in production. Planned is a strong word.

Comment: So 6 - 8 weeks?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that it's always referred to as a "weekly" podcast on the podcast, and yet it never turns out that way. Good stuff though.

Comment: It's "6-8 weekly".